# Merge large list of data frames into one data frame by columns

Tags: r, list, merge, dplyr

I need to merge a large list (aprox 15 data frames [16000x6]).
Each data frame has 2 id columns `"A"` and `"B"` plus 4 columns with information.

I want to have the first two (`"A"` and `"B"` plus 15*4 columns in one data frame).

I have found this in another question:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="your tag here"),your_list_here)
```

However this, crashes my machine giving this error because it needs too much RAM (only using a list with 3 dfs!)

```
 In make.unique(as.character(rows)) :
  Reached total allocation of 4060Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I believe there must be a better strategy, I started with `bind_cols` from `dplyr` package and it gets me really fast a data frame with duplicated A and B columns. Maybe removing these columns, keeping the first two, is a better approach.

I provide you a small toy list (the Reduce(...) strategy works here but I need another solution)

```
dput(mylist)
structure(list(df1 = structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
    B = c("Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P"), x1 = c(0.45840139570646, 
    0.0418491987511516, 0.798411589581519, 0.898478724062443, 
    0.064307059859857, 0.174364002654329), x2 = c(0.676136856665835, 
    0.494200984947383, 0.534940708894283, 0.220597118837759, 
    0.480761741055176, 0.0230771545320749)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    df2 = structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), B = c("Q", 
    "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P"), x1 = c(0.45840139570646, 0.0418491987511516, 
    0.798411589581519, 0.898478724062443, 0.064307059859857, 
    0.174364002654329), x2 = c(0.676136856665835, 0.494200984947383, 
    0.534940708894283, 0.220597118837759, 0.480761741055176, 
    0.0230771545320749)), .Names = c("A", "B", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"), df3 = structure(list(A = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 3), B = c("Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P"), x1 = c(0.45840139570646, 
    0.0418491987511516, 0.798411589581519, 0.898478724062443, 
    0.064307059859857, 0.174364002654329), x2 = c(0.676136856665835, 
    0.494200984947383, 0.534940708894283, 0.220597118837759, 
    0.480761741055176, 0.0230771545320749)), .Names = c("A", 
    "B", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("df1", 
"df2", "df3"))
```

Comment: could you explain a little bit more / show some code? how do I 'store' the 15 dfs in a loop for merge to work? I thought of split and merge but again, I need "somewhere" to put those dfs

Comment: What do you expect to happen with duplicate keys? I suspect this is what is blowing up your computer. There are two entries for "1 Q" and two for "3 P". Do you really just want to cbind these datasets?

Comment: @Zelazny7 Yes, I am sure I want cbind + merge by id columns. Rememeber I have 16000 rows per df, I'd prefer to have a 16000*62 than a huge tall df. Also, later I have a lot of code that is column based, many functions that take those id colums and modify the other columns that I don't want to code again. What I originally did is manually subset but I need to make this better now.

Comment: It's unclear how you want to match the rows. Do the factors "A" and "B" provide a unique id for each row, or are the rows already in the right order and you only need to concatenate the columns?

Comment: @ErnestA The rows are in correct order, both answers produce the correct output

Comment: So, it is not merging but `cbind`.

Comment: @ well if df were separated it would be merging I guess ? I use manual subset (same strategy as cbind) nowadays but I needed something more user friendly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment stating you want a 16,000 x 62 data.frame...

First cbind the non ID columns:

```
tmp <- do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) x[,-(1:2)]))
```

Then add "A" and "B"

```
final <- cbind(mylist[[1]][,1:2], tmp)
```

No merging needed, just slap the data.frames together

```
> final
  A B     df1.x1     df1.x2     df2.x1     df2.x2     df3.x1     df3.x2
1 1 Q 0.45840140 0.67613686 0.45840140 0.67613686 0.45840140 0.67613686
2 1 Q 0.04184920 0.49420098 0.04184920 0.49420098 0.04184920 0.49420098
3 2 Q 0.79841159 0.53494071 0.79841159 0.53494071 0.79841159 0.53494071
4 2 P 0.89847872 0.22059712 0.89847872 0.22059712 0.89847872 0.22059712
5 3 P 0.06430706 0.48076174 0.06430706 0.48076174 0.06430706 0.48076174
6 3 P 0.17436400 0.02307715 0.17436400 0.02307715 0.17436400 0.02307715
```

Comment: The OP says that each data.frame has 16,000 rows. If there are duplicate IDs, a Reduce/merge will produce a data.frame with more than 16,000 rows in the final output. The OP also states in a comment that the final dimensions should be 16,000 x 62.

Answer (score 4):

For `cbind`-ing the dataframes you can do:

```
L <- mylist[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(mylist)) L <- cbind(L,  mylist[[i]][-(1:2)])
```

For `merge`-ing (as in the former shown (but wrong) expected output for the example):

```
L <- mylist[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(mylist)) L <- merge(L,  mylist[[i]], by=c("A", "B"))
```

In the case of `merge`-ing I suppose the need of memory comes from the m:n-connections among the dataframes. This is not solvable by another procedure for merging.

Comment: I like this approach, I suspect merge checks if "A" and "B" are equal? and produces error if not